# How can we restrict users to entering ONLY certain topics in Chatter posts

Tags: chatter

I am ware that we can prevent users from creating / editing Topics in Chatter posts.

But is there a way that we can restrict users to entering only certain topics (using the # notation) ?

My initial thinking is to enter a list of allowed topics into the Topics table & then have a check against that table each time a post is created.

But I am unsure of whether SF API will allow this approach.

Look forward to your ideas & suggestions

Comment: If the create topic permission is removed for a user, they won't be able to post with unidentified topic.